# Hide values from drop-down choice list in NewForm.aspx using jQuery

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, jquery, newform

In a SharePoint 2016 list, I have a choice column (appropriately named 'Choice') where I would like to hide certain values in NewForm.aspx.

- Choice 1
- Choice 2
- Choice 3

(I'm trying to hide Choice 2.)

I've got jQuery saved in the Site Assets document library on this same site, and the following script (called "HideChoices.js")

```
<script src="../SiteAssets/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dropdown = $(":input[title='Choice']");
    dropdown.find("option[value='Choice 2']").remove();
});
</script>
```

I added a link to HideChoices.js to the main web part on NewForm.aspx, but it breaks and I'm not really sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: What's the error that you get?

Comment: The page's formatting is broken initially, then trying to click on the New Item link (to access NewPage.aspx) freezes at "Working on it..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to put the following scripts to HideChoices.js file and upload this file to Site Assets document library -> jQuery folder.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  var dropdown = $(":input[title='Choice']");
  dropdown.find("option[value='Choice 2']").remove();
});
```

Then, edit the main web part on NewForm.aspx. Go to **Miscellaneous -> JS Link**. Add the following property into the JS Link textbox.

```
~site/SiteAssets/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js|~site/SiteAssets/jQuery/HideChoices.js
```

Note:

The format of JSLink proiperty is “`~site/<library>/<file>`”. Change the value in “<>”.

For example: If you uploaded the JavaScript file custom.js into the Site Assets library, the value for the JSLink property can be "`~site/SiteAssets/custom.js`".